# VS Code - Powershell Modules - Command not recognised

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, powershell-module

I am a little perplexed by this, i've been using VS Code for Writing PowerShell for over a year and had no issues until recently when it has started to reject fairly standard cmdlets as unknown.

Today I was trying to use Get-Eventlog

`Get-EventLog -logname security -instanceid 4624`

but I keep getting this error:

```
Get-EventLog: The term 'Get-EventLog' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again
```

According to MS Docs Get-EventLog is part of the
Microsoft.PowerShell.Management module so I checked to see if it is loaded

```
get-module


ModuleType Version    PreRelease Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ---------- ----                                ----------------
Manifest   7.0.0.0               Microsoft.PowerShell.Management     {Add-Content, Clear-Content, Clear-Item, Clear-It…
Manifest   3.1.0.0               Microsoft.PowerShell.Management     {Add-Content, Clear-Content, Clear-Item, Clear-It…
Manifest   7.0.0.0               Microsoft.PowerShell.Security       {ConvertFrom-SecureString, ConvertTo-SecureString…
Manifest   7.0.0.0               Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility        {Add-Member, Add-Type, Clear-Variable, Compare-Ob…
Script     0.2.0                 PowerShellEditorServices.Commands   {Clear-Host, ConvertFrom-ScriptExtent, ConvertTo-…
Binary     0.2.0                 PowerShellEditorServices.VSCode     {Close-VSCodeHtmlContentView, New-VSCodeHtmlConte…
Script     2.1.0                 PSReadLine                          {Get-PSReadLineKeyHandler, Get-PSReadLineOption, …
```

It appears to be in the V3.1.0.0 version

```
get-command get-* | where source -eq Microsoft.PowerShell.Management


CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Cmdlet          Get-ChildItem                                      7.0.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management
Cmdlet          Get-Clipboard                                      7.0.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management
Cmdlet          Get-ComputerInfo                                   7.0.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management
Cmdlet          Get-ComputerRestorePoint                           3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management
Cmdlet          Get-Content                                        7.0.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management
Cmdlet          Get-ControlPanelItem                               3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management
Cmdlet          Get-EventLog                                       3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management
Cmdlet          Get-HotFix                                         7.0.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management
Cmdlet          Get-Item                                           7.0.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management
Cmdlet          Get-ItemProperty                                   7.0.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management
Cmdlet          Get-ItemPropertyValue                              7.0.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management
Cmdlet          Get-Location                                       7.0.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management
Cmdlet          Get-Process                                        7.0.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management
Cmdlet          Get-PSDrive                                        7.0.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management
Cmdlet          Get-PSProvider                                     7.0.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management
Cmdlet          Get-Service                                        7.0.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management
Cmdlet          Get-TimeZone                                       7.0.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management
Cmdlet          Get-Transaction                                    3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management
Cmdlet          Get-WmiObject                                      3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management
```

but is absolutely not recognised in the (same) VSCode terminal window

```
get-command get-eventlog

Get-Command: The term 'get-eventlog' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

I removed the Microsoft.PowerShell.Management module

`remove-module Microsoft.PowerShell.Management`

confirmed that it had gone

```
get-module


ModuleType Version    PreRelease Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ---------- ----                                ----------------
Manifest   7.0.0.0               Microsoft.PowerShell.Security       {ConvertFrom-SecureString, ConvertTo-SecureString…
Manifest   7.0.0.0               Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility        {Add-Member, Add-Type, Clear-Variable, Compare-Ob…
Script     0.2.0                 PowerShellEditorServices.Commands   {Clear-Host, ConvertFrom-ScriptExtent, ConvertTo-…
Binary     0.2.0                 PowerShellEditorServices.VSCode     {Close-VSCodeHtmlContentView, New-VSCodeHtmlConte…
Script     2.1.0                 PSReadLine                          {Get-PSReadLineKeyHandler, Get-PSReadLineOption, …
```

and then  tried again

```
get-eventlog

get-eventlog: The term 'get-eventlog' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

The module was reloaded but the cmdlet isn't seen...

```
get-module


ModuleType Version    PreRelease Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ---------- ----                                ----------------
Manifest   3.1.0.0               Microsoft.PowerShell.Management     {Add-Content, Clear-Content, Clear-Item, Clear-It…
Manifest   7.0.0.0               Microsoft.PowerShell.Security       {ConvertFrom-SecureString, ConvertTo-SecureString…
Manifest   7.0.0.0               Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility        {Add-Member, Add-Type, Clear-Variable, Compare-Ob…
Script     0.2.0                 PowerShellEditorServices.Commands   {Clear-Host, ConvertFrom-ScriptExtent, ConvertTo-…
Binary     0.2.0                 PowerShellEditorServices.VSCode     {Close-VSCodeHtmlContentView, New-VSCodeHtmlConte…
Script     2.1.0                 PSReadLine                          {Get-PSReadLineKeyHandler, Get-PSReadLineOption, …
```

`$env:PSModulePath` contains the following paths

```
C:\Users\<username>\Documents\PowerShell\Modules;
C:\Program Files\PowerShell\Modules;
c:\program files\powershell\7\Modules;
C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;
C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules;
C:\Program Files\SharePoint Online Management Shell\;
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Skype for Business Online\Modules\;
c:\Users\<username>\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.powershell-2021.6.2\modules
```

I am very confused - any suggestions anybody?

Comment: you appear to be running PS7  ... and that cmdlet is NOT supported there at this time. lookee ... Get-EventLog (Microsoft.PowerShell.Management) - PowerShell | Microsoft Docs — https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-eventlog?view=powershell-5.1&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-7

Comment: You can configure VS Code to use _Windows PowerShell_, which sounds like what you need.

Comment: I have v7 and v5.1 installed ... biut you are correct and I've confirmed that with $PSVersionTable - VSCode has somehow chosen to use V7 I haven't told it to a with all but very specific scripts written using V5.1 - Any idea how to change the PS version used by VSCode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As indicated by @lee_Dailey and @mklement0 VSCode had configured itself to use V7.1.3 (pwsh) rather than 5.1 (Powershell.exe) I am assuming now that this occurred either during an upgrade of VSCode or an upgrade of pwsh as it happened on two machines that both have V7 installed and received both updates at a similar time.

**To Correct**
Use the command palette (CTRL-SHIFT_P) search for "session" choose "PowerShell:Show Session Menu" and select "Session:Windows Powershell" using the correct one for your architecture.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your instructions have solved my local issue. Thanks again.